# F# connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, f#

I am new to F#, I have been looking for a way to connect to MongoDB that's on my local machine.

I have been finding it difficult to find an documentation on this process. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or is it possible to connect using a c# driver?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The top two search results from [this search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=F%23+mongodb&go=) should provide you what you need.